# how to implement navigation drawer and google maps activity together

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation-drawer

Hello I am making an app and i am not able to implement navigation drawer and google maps activity together in a layout. I want to add map activity in the navigation drawer like the way ola app works.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    Intent intent9 = new Intent(this, Maps.class);
    startActivity(intent9);// Adding map activity

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.map, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
     if (id == R.id.nav_scheduled) {

        Intent intent5 = new Intent(this, ScheduledTimings.class);
        startActivity(intent5);
    }
    else if (id == R.id.nav_contact) {

        Intent intent6 = new Intent(this, EmergencyContact.class);
        startActivity(intent6);
    }
    else if (id==R.id.nav_feedback){
        Intent intent10 = new Intent(this, Feedback.class);
        startActivity(intent10);
    }
    else if (id == R.id.nav_about) {

        Intent intent7 = new Intent(this, About.class);
        startActivity(intent7);
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried so far?

Comment: use MapView in fragment and use that fragment in the main activity in which navigation drawer implemented

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried to do? In the code above, I see only a drawer implementation, what about the Map?

I suggest you do this way:

Implement the drawer in the main activity, here use a fragment and in the fragment insert a MapView.

Should works.